# Complex line integral for closed homotopic curve.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-integration

I try to show that the following analogous result for $\textbf{closed curve}$ :

Let $\gamma_0, \gamma_1$ be continuous paths in a domain $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ and $\omega$ be a closed form on $D$. If $\gamma_0$ is homotopic to $\gamma_1$ with their end points fixed (so they are not closed curve), then $\int_{\gamma_0} \omega = \int_{\gamma_1} \omega$.

This is what I try so far :

Let $\gamma_0, \gamma_1 : [0,1] \rightarrow D$ with $\gamma_i(0) = \gamma_i(1)$ for $i = 1,2$. Let $H$ be a homotopy between closed curve $\gamma_0, \gamma_1$ ($H : [0,1] \times [0,1] \rightarrow D$). Let $f$ be a primitive of $\omega$ along $H$ (it existence is confirmed by a theorem). Then $$\int_{\gamma_0} \omega = f(1,0) - f(0,0)$$ because $f(t,0)$ is a primitive for $\omega$ along $\gamma_0$. Also $$\int_{\gamma_1} \omega = f(1,1) - f(0,1).$$ This method works for any non-closed curves since their end points are fixed and equal such that $f(1,0) = f(1,1), f(0,0) = f(0,1)$. But this fact is not true for closed curves since each of them might do not share any points in common.

Here are some $\textbf{definitions}$ involved in solving this problem :

$\textbf{Definition 1}$ A domain $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is an open connected set.

$\textbf{Definition 2}$ A differential form $\omega$ is exact on $D$ if there exists a $C^1$-function $F$ ($F$ has continuous first derivative) on D such that $\omega = dF$.
$\omega$ is closed form if for each $c\in D$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $c$ such that the restriction $\omega|_U$ is exact.

For definitions concerning homotopy between curves, I can provide you if it is needed (the definition is quite long). Also, as a reference, all information can be found in Complex Analysis in spirit of Lipman Bers (2nd edition)

Thank you in advanced for help.

$\textbf{I come up with some ideas as follows}$
Between the two closed path I draw two lines connecting these two paths. Then I have two news paths (Actually, one of them is the old path) with common fixed starting and ending points. Then I apply the theorem for non-closed paths. With some adjustment, I think that can obtain the result. Is this idea possible ? Any comment,please ?

Comment: Apply Stoke's theorem to the homotopy (which is a parameterized rectangle in the domain).

Comment: @StevenGubkin I try to understand what you mean. Can you explain more or give more hints ? As far as I know, the two homotopic curves $\gamma_0, \gamma_1$ can be any closed curve different from rectangle (curve). It might be the cases that these two curves always homotoic to some rectangle(curve), but I do not see why this fact is true.

Comment: Precisely, do you mean that my homotopy function $H$ has a box domain (I mean rectangle $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ which is a square in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $\int_{\partial H} \omega = \int_H d\omega$.

Comment: I update some ideas that I think it is going to work. Can anyone review it ? It at the bottom of the main post.